# How to find to find 'today at midnight' in .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, timezone, datetimeoffset

We have a cron job scheduled at 'every day 3pm paris,' 'every day 3pm new york,' etc

In our code, the logic is to find all transactions realized between midnight and noon in the specified timezone

Currently, we are doing this to find midnight (then adding `AddHours(12)` to find noon)

```
var tz = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById(tzId); //tzId is a param of the job
var midnightAtTz = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(DateTimeOffset.UtcNow, tz).Date;
```

It seems to work, however we do not understand why and we do not understand what would be the correct way to do it

Some things that do not work but would make more sense

```
DateTime.Today => relies on the server TZ
TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(DateTime.Today, tz).Date; => throws exception if tz is not the one of the machine, System.ArgumentException: The UTC Offset of the local dateTime parameter does not match the offset argument. (Parameter 'offset')
```

Questions:

1. Why is `.Date` working fine even if this is `DateTime` and not `DateTimeOffset`?
2. Is this the correct way to find midnight in a specific timezone?

Comment: One thing you need to think about is what you want to happen if the target time happens twice, or not all. (Some time zones "spring forward" at midnight, for example.)

Comment: You could use NodaTime to do this

Comment: The first snippet uses DateTimeOffset and the second one uses DateTime. These are very different when it comes to working with time zones. DateTime can only do local, UTC and unspecified so using it with arbitrary time zone is not possible. Or at least it's not exactly easy.

Comment: I am suspicious that it no longer will work as soon as you are crossing the date- border. Do you have unit tests covering offsets around 12h?

Comment: ^^ I'd also recommend Noda, because you can idiomatically tell it to give you "an instant in time in utc that represents the same instant on a specific date at a specific local time of a specific timezone, respecting daylight savings".

Comment: @Fildor I'm looking for pure c# solution (without Noda)  and an explantion why the other things do not work
Also, I do not have unit tests because I have the same problem in tests => I'm unsure how to test correctly in other timezones...

Comment: @JonSkeet good point !
The question would be : how can you find the start of the current day in a specific timezone ?
I undersatnd why you need to use DateTimeOffset.UtcNow and not DateTime.Today (because only UTC is possible with DateTime)
But I still do not undersatnd why using .Date is working ...

Please mind that the cron job is done by GCP Cloud scheduler, so I suppose they are correctly dealing with daylights savings ...

Comment: Ok, so given the scheduler fires at that local time (3.pm local), then a UtcNow will be around that instant in time (a little later perhaps). Then converting that utc time into the respective timezone will be around  3pm local. `.Date` strips the time information and thus your result is that Date at 00:00 local.  + 12h is that Date at 12:00 local.

Comment: @ChristopheBlin: Well, I'd personally use Noda Time and its `DateTimeZone.AtStartOfDay` method, but as the author of Noda Time, I'm biased :) I'm sure it's feasible just with `TimeZoneInfo`, but I strongly suspect it'll be fiddly. (I know you said you want a "pure C#" solution, but if you're doing any significant amount of date/time work, I really would *consider* moving to Noda Time, at least for internal computations. You can always convert to/from DateTimeOffset or whatever at API boundaries.)

Comment: @ChristopheBlin I came up with this: https://dotnetfiddle.net/9T75Bv can you tell me if that's what you are looking for? If so, then I would make it an answer with more detailed explanation.

Comment: @ChristopheBlin Are you OK with me changing the title, so the Q won't be considered "Opinion based" any longer? If not, just revert my change.

Comment: What about using `DateTimeOffset`?

Comment: Using DTO alone will leave you with incorrect data twice a year for every location that utilizes daylight savings. @Pieterjan

Comment: @Fildor fiddle and Q modif => ok

The only thing I do not fully understand : ".Date strips the time information and thus your result is that Date at 00:00 local" => ok with that but .Date "reverts" to DateTime instead of DateTimeOffset, why is it still working ?

If you mind writing your comment as an answer, I'll mark it as solved

Comment: Question is still closed, so cannot write an answer. But to your question: you convert a DTO, get its Date property, which is DateTime. If you put a DateTime into the convert method, it's a different overload with slightly different behavior. Not sure what could cause that specific error, though. Documentation doesn't mention that one.

Comment: @Fildor I've reopened the question. You can answer now if you wish.